# Why will "ls" not list files starting with "." in Linux

Tags: linux

I was searching for a "`.android`" folder and used `ls` all over the place, until I decided to use `locate` (after an `updatedb`) and found that it was in my `/home/johndoe/` folder all along.  When I `ls` on the folder, the `.android` folder is not listed.  Can someone please explain why this is not listing for me with my beloved `ls` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Files and folders beginning with `.` are hidden files in a typical UNIX-like OS.

Use `ls -a` to list all files.

Answer (score 5):

Traditionally, in UNIX and UNIX-like operating systems, the `.` prefix means a *hidden* file, similar to the "Hidden" flag in Windows. It works anywhere, but its primary use is to hide configuration files in your home directory (e.g. `~/.cache/` or `~/.plan` – they're frequently called "dotfiles").

To force `ls` to display hidden files, you need the `-a` option.

Almost all graphical file managers also honor this prefix; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> toggles "hidden" files in GNOME.

---

As Rob Pike [writes on Google+](https://plus.google.com/101960720994009339267/posts/R58WgWwN9jp), this was an accidental feature:

> Long ago, as the design of the Unix file system was being worked out, the entries . and .. appeared, to make navigation easier. I'm not sure but I believe .. went in during the Version 2 rewrite, when the file system became hierarchical (it had a very different structure early on).  When one typed ls, however, these files appeared, so either Ken or Dennis added a simple test to the program. It was in assembler then, but the code in question was equivalent to something like this:
>
> `if (name[0] == '.') continue;`
>
> This statement was a little shorter than what it should have been, which is
>
> `if (strcmp(name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(name, "..") == 0) continue;`
>
> but hey, it was easy.
>
> Two things resulted.
>
> First, a bad precedent was set. A lot of other lazy programmers introduced bugs by making the same simplification. Actual files beginning with periods are often skipped when they should be counted.
>
> Second, and much worse, the idea of a "hidden" or "dot" file was created. As a consequence, more lazy programmers started dropping files into everyone's home directory. I don't have all that much stuff installed on the machine I'm using to type this, but my home directory has about a hundred dot files and I don't even know what most of them are or whether they're still needed. Every file name evaluation that goes through my home directory is slowed down by this accumulated sludge.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the "-a" for ["all"](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_ls.htm) parameter for ls to display dot files.